# Trying to count existing files with array walk, getting "Only variables can be passed by reference"

Tags: php, arrays

```
existingReports[$i] 
= count(array_walk(file_exists,$data['reports'][$i]));
```

Is something wrong with this statement?

For example

```
print_r($filename[3]);

[0] => uploads/2011-05-10%20Philippines%20Philippine%20storm%2022%20dead.pdf 

[1] => uploads/2011-05-10%20Philippines%20Philippine%20storm%2022%20dead.pdf 

[2] => uploads/2011-05-10%20Philippines%20Philippine%20storm%2022%20dead.pdf 

[3] => uploads/2011-05-12%20Philippines%20Nestle%20noodles.jpg 

[4] => uploads/2011-05-12%20Philippines%20Nestle%20noodles.jpg 

[5] => uploads/2011-05-12%20Philippines%20Nestle%20noodles.jpg 

[6] => uploads/2011-05-13%20Algeria%20TESTTEST
```

Obviously I am checking to see which of those reports exists, I will also need to dedupe them now that I am looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use <s>`array_map`</s> [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) here instead:

```
= count(array_filter($data['reports'][$i], "file_exists"));
```

Of course, the first parameter still needs to contain an array. If it matches your example output of `print_r($filename[3]);` it should work however.

Comment: Hah! That is odd, it is returning that everything passed through it exists!

Comment: Yeah, array_map is not useful for what you actually want. `array_filter` is the correct method, does not require a second step.

Comment: This works, but I am having other trouble, (raw)urlencode is apparently not good for testing existence.